# What are the differences between kotlin variable functions and common fun functions?

Tags: android, function, kotlin, var

There is a fun method0:

```
    private fun method0() {
        println("method0 fun")
    }
```

And a  var method0 :

```
    var method0 = {
        println("method0")
    }
```

It seems they are used the same:

```
    method0()
```

I found that both occur at the same time, and the fun function has a higher priority when the code calls.
Other than that, is there any difference between them?

Comment: What you call wrongly a _variable function_ is called a lambda. You should read https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html. Especially the part titled _Lambda expression syntax_, but be aware that in the end you need to read the whole page.

Comment: Well, it's a *variable with a functional type* and a function declared using *lambda syntax*. The thing as a whole is not a lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `var` way of doing it results in a functional object. The lambda content is wrapped as a functional object so it can be passed around like any other instance of a class. It can directly be used as a function parameter, for instance.

```
var method0 = {
    println("method0")
}

fun doSomethingTwice(action: ()->Unit) {
    repeat(2) { action() }
}

fun main() {
    doSomethingTwice(method0)
}
```

And since it's marked as a `var` you can swap it out for a different function:

```
fun main() {
    method0 = { println("hello, world!") }
    doSomethingTwice(method0)
}
```

Note that this way of specifying a function is a little bit heavier since it is wrapping the function in another class instance.

And you can still wrap any "regular" function into a functional object at any time by using `::` to avoid doing it until it's necessary.

```
fun method0() {
    println("method0")
}

fun main() {
    doSomethingTwice(::method0)
}
```